# `try`/`except` block not working in pandas apply function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to apply a function to `pandas` dataframe. My function has a `try/except` block to catch exceptions like `ZeroDivisionError` but it's failing.

Data Frame have 100+ columns. And **actual** function is to be applied every row by selecting subset of columns

Following is my code

Function:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def d(x):
    x0=22/7
    try:
        return x0/x
    except:
        return 0

df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,2,3,4],'b':[0,3,4,5]})
df

Out[174]: 
   a  b
0  0  0
1  2  3
2  3  4
3  4  5
```

After applying Function as

```
df.apply(lambda x:d(x))

Out[173]: 
          a         b
0       inf       inf
1  1.571429  1.047619
2  1.047619  0.785714
3  0.785714  0.628571
```

Expected `0` instead of `inf` at index `0`

```
Out[173]: 
          a         b
0  0.000000  0.000000
1  1.571429  1.047619
2  1.047619  0.785714
3  0.785714  0.628571
```

Can anyone let me know what am I missing here. It's frustrating.... :@

Comment: If you only expect to catch `ZeroDivisionError`, you should say so explicitly. Never use a bare `except`, and try to catch the smallest set of exceptions you actually know how to handle.

Comment: Apaprently, dividing by 0 in this context does not trigger an exception. It's not that the "catch" does not work, it's the fact that no exception are raised.

Answer (score 4):

Specify column:

```
df[0].apply(lambda x : d(x))
```

Out:

```
0    0.000000
1    3.142857
2    1.571429
3    1.047619
4    0.785714
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

For entire dataset use: df.applymap(d)

Comment: Thanks but doesn't help. Data Frame have 100+ columns. And this function is to be applied every row by selecting subset of columns.

Comment: `.applymap` is going to perform terribly compared with the other solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative which will be faster than using `apply` if your real dataset is very large:

```
import math
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 2, 3, 4], 'b': [0, 3, 4, 5]})
df = (math.pi / df).replace(np.inf, 0)
```

Results:

```
          a         b
0  0.000000  0.000000
1  1.570796  1.047198
2  1.047198  0.785398
3  0.785398  0.628319
```

Comment: Sorry, point here is not to catching exception when Divide by Zero happens. Not to make it efficient

Comment: @Mansoor The purpose of a solution should be to fix the actual problem, not the tangential problem you think you may have. With `d(x)` there is never an exception, so there is nothing to catch. This solution accomplishes exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: @ALollz. Well, thanks for ur reply... But I disagree... sometimes. It's simple as such. I have an alternate way to do this. Wanted to know why there's NO execution of "except" block if there is any exception!